# Types of polymorphism. More than one?

Tags: c#, java, polymorphism

I am still in college and only remember about hearing about 1 type of polymorphism when learning about Java; however, when I was in a C# class, I just remember my professor talking about 4 types of polymorphism.

I am only aware of subclassing and defining specific behavior within more specific classes, and being able to call those specific behaviors with a single method in the base class because of an interface signature.

What are the other types, and are they of as big of an importance as the only type we were taught above? Is that why there are not taught?

Comment: I thought the whole point of polymorphism was that behavior could vary by allowing multiple `types`... See what I did there? :-D

Comment: Your best bet is to ask your professor what these "4 types of polymorphism" are in your particular course... There interpretation of it you can find here are probably not going to help you on your exams...

Comment: According to Wikipedia, there are only [three types of polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science)#Forms_of_polymorphism).

Comment: yeah...I am still on summer vacation. But I just remember her saying that. I passed over my head back then...but was enough to stay stuck in memory I guess...well the fact that there are more than one.

Comment: @Jeffrey - The Wikipedia article is contradicted by one of its references (Cardelli & Wegner)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes there are 4 kinds of polymorphism

1. **Overloading**  (Same function names, different parameter types.  This includes operator overloading and is done at compile time)
2. **Parametric polymorphism**  (These are like templates in C++)  Compile time
3. **Subtype polymorphism** (if a function has a parameter with a subtype, for example Car->Honda, f(Car), then function f will accept f(Honda) as well.)  Runtime
4. **Parameter coercion**  (This is an implicit type conversion.  For example, a function might require a double/real/float, but will accept an int and will implicitly upcast the parameter)
   Compile time

Reference:

- ["On Understanding Types, Data Abstraction, and Polymorphism"](http://lucacardelli.name/Papers/OnUnderstanding.A4.pdf) by Cardelli & Wegner.

Comment: Thanks! So they are basically what we DID learn...they just go by different names...like Overloading, which is the easiest to remember and do

Comment: +1 You left out the **IGiveUpPolymorphismThatIllFixLaterButLaterMeansNever** where you (ab)use `dynamic` or `switch`.